# CSS body background causing errors with no repeat

Tags: html, css, background

This may be a stupid question but I am trying to set a static background image onto the body of my site but I don't want to repeat the image. I have this:

```
body{
    background:url(../assessts/BG.png) center bottom no-repeat,#000;
    background-size:100% auto;
}
```

Which doesn't show the image at all, however if I remove the  no-repeat:

```
body{
    background:url(../assessts/BG.png) center bottom,#000;
    background-size:100% auto;
}
```

This shows the image fine. The image is quite large anyway and fills my 19 inch screen well without the no-repeat option. But as a fail safe for very large screens I would like the image not to repeat.

Where I am more confused is I have a div later on in the CSS that using a similar method:

```
.head{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:0px;
    background:url(../assessts/logo.png) center -60px no-repeat,#000;
    background-size:300px auto;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    display:block;
    box-shadow:0px 4px 4px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 4px 2px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 4px 2px #000;

}
```

But this works with no errors. If I'm not mistaking it is the same?

Comment: Are body and HTML are set to be 100% width?

Comment: No but I tried setting the width and height to 100% and now it works. I'm not sure but does it have to have a size to function the same way as it would for a div width a fixed size?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rearranging the order of the properties, i.e. `background: #000 url(../assessts/BG.png) no-repeat center bottom;`   See [W3C notes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) on shorthand property order.

Comment: that doesn't work at all, isn't the color supposed to be loaded last?

Comment: From the horses mouth (see link above): "When using the shorthand property the order of the property values is: background-color, background-image, background-repeat, background-attachment, background-position.  It does not matter if one of the property values is missing, as long as the ones that are present are in this order."